# useTable прятать колонки по чекбоксу

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Такая проблема, что я использую библиотеку useTable и мне надо прятать колонки по чекбоксу. это все прекрасно работает через метод который изображен на скрине. Но мне нужно, что бы все спряталась, когда нажму на кнопку сохранить, можно ли как-то метод ...column.getToggleHiddenProps()} повесить на кнопку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

вот пример реализаций, с разделением состояния на промежуточное в списке фильтра и основное для отрисовки колонок в таблице

[image: пример реализаций]

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useTable } from "react-table";

const data = [
  {
    col1: "Hello",
    col2: "World",
  },
  {
    col1: "react-table",
    col2: "rocks",
  },
  {
    col1: "whatever",
    col2: "you want",
  },
];

const columns = [
  {
    Header: "Column 1",
    accessor: "col1", // accessor is the "key" in the data
  },
  {
    Header: "Column 2",
    accessor: "col2",
  },
];

const getStateDropdown = (filter: string[]) =>
  columns
    .map((column) => column.accessor)
    .filter((column) => !filter.includes(column));

/* #region  */
interface DropdownProps {
  filter: string[];
  onApply: (filter: string[]) => () => void;
  onCancel: () => void;
}

const Dropdown = (props: DropdownProps) => {
  const { filter, onApply, onCancel } = props;
  const [state, setState] = useState(filter);
  const handleChange = (field: string, flag: boolean) => () => {
    if (flag) {
      const nextFilter = [...state, field];
      return setState(nextFilter);
    }

    if (!flag) {
      const nextFilter = state.filter((key) => key !== field);
      return setState(nextFilter);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Dropdown.Ul>
      <Dropdown.Li>filter: {JSON.stringify(state)}</Dropdown.Li>
      {columns.map((column) => {
        const isChecked = state.includes(column.accessor);
        return (
          <Dropdown.Li key={column.accessor}>
            <Dropdown.Label>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={isChecked}
                onChange={handleChange(column.accessor, !isChecked)}
              />
              <span>{column.Header}</span>
            </Dropdown.Label>
          </Dropdown.Li>
        );
      })}
      <Dropdown.Li>
        <button onClick={onApply(state)}>Сохранить</button>
        <button onClick={onCancel}>Отмена</button>
      </Dropdown.Li>
    </Dropdown.Ul>
  );
};

Dropdown.Ul = styled.ul`
  display: block;
`;

Dropdown.Li = styled.li`
  display: block;
`;

Dropdown.Label = styled.label`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-left: 10px;
  gap: 10px;
`;
/* #endregion */

/* #region Пример из документаций */
interface TableProps {
  columns: typeof columns;
  data: typeof data;
}
const Table = ({ columns, data }: TableProps) => {
  // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
  // @ts-ignore
  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = useTable({ columns, data });

  // Render the UI for your table
  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
/* #endregion */

/* #region Questions1318331 */

const useFilter = () => {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(getStateDropdown([]));
  const [isVisibleDropDown, setVisibleDropDown] = useState(false);
  const handleFilterUpdate = useCallback(
    (filter: string[]) => () => {
      setFilter(filter);
      setVisibleDropDown(false);
    },
    []
  );
  const handleToggleClick = () => setVisibleDropDown((prev) => !prev);

  return { filter, isVisibleDropDown, handleToggleClick, handleFilterUpdate };
};

const Questions1318331 = () => {
  const filterData = useFilter();
  const { filter, isVisibleDropDown } = filterData;
  const { handleToggleClick, handleFilterUpdate } = filterData;

  const listOfColumns = useMemo(() => {
    return columns.filter((column) => filter.includes(column.accessor));
  }, [filter]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleToggleClick}>
        Edit filter - {JSON.stringify(filter)}
      </button>
      {isVisibleDropDown && (
        <Dropdown
          filter={filter}
          onApply={handleFilterUpdate}
          onCancel={handleToggleClick}
        />
      )}
      <Table columns={listOfColumns} data={data} />
    </>
  );
};

Questions1318331.Filter = styled.div`
  position: relative;

  ${Dropdown.Ul} {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translate(10px, 0);
  }
`;

export { Questions1318331 };
/* #endregion */
```

Comment: прошу Вас оценить или дать обратную связь если я правильно понял вопрос